# ERROR: layout-large already exists. Use a different qualifier

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have two layouts, for one I create more layouts for different screen sizes.  But when I do the same for the latter I get this error. For example, there is a "Large" for mainlayout but not for the second layout, still, I am taking this error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

OK is disabled.

Comment: Can you please post your whole `res` folder structure?  because it's most likely that folder named `layout-large` is already there.

Comment: I added it, yes there i a folder already but I cant change the folder name, it is default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio displays your project files in the **`Android`** view. This view does not reflect the actual file hierarchy on disk. To see the actual file structure of the project including all files hidden from the ***Android*** view, select **`Project`** from the dropdown at the top of the Project window.

When ever you changed then you see **`layout-large`** already exists in your `res` folder.

For custom layout folder, Go into your modules `gradle.build` file and create a **sourceSets** definition like below

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res',
                       'src/main/res/layouts/custom_layout_folder_name'
                       
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sir I see, but I cant change the name folder, it is default. Now I am adding a pic, check it please. You will understand clearly.

Comment: @BurhanYaprak `but I cant change the name folder` Okay create another

Comment: I added a pic on my question(check my question above pls), I can not add a new for example layout-small, OK button is disabled. It just allows to default name(layout-small) but error: it is already created.  I couldn't still solve it.

Comment: @BurhanYaprak Hope this help you. https://medium.com/programming-lite/layouts-in-different-folders-in-android-app-98468bd507c7

Comment: Thank you so much for this article, I will check it now, if I solve it, I will add a solution here.

Comment: @BurhanYaprak https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f